# How to log non-fatal exceptions with Crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I started using Firebase (Crashlytics) in my project to track app crashes. It works perfectly with crashes but how can I log non-fatal crashes, i.e. caught exceptions. I tried `Crashlytics.logException(e)` but it doesn't work. I see no reports in the dashboard. I saw answers suggesting to use `FirebaseCrash.report(t)` but this class doesn't exist in the latest version of Firebase. So does anyone know how it's done?

Dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

[image]

Comment: Did you kill and restart your app after you logged the exception?

Comment: Even on the latest version of Crashlytics, `Crashlytics.logException(ex)` is the way to go. Are you testing on a debug or a release build? I've never had problems logging non-fatals with `Crashlytics.logException(ex)`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It does work after all. It seems it just takes longer time until non-fatal exceptions are shown in the dashboard or like @DougStevenson said you have to kill and restart the app.

Comment: +1 on needing to kill and restart the app. My test app has a foreground service, so I had to reinstall the app to get a new process before the report is uploaded. FYI you'll see this in logcat when the events are sent back up to Firebase Crashlytics: `I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: `

Comment: Is firebase sync with `implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'` dependency ??

Answer (score 64, accepted):

With the new Firebase Crashlytics you should use `recordException(@NonNull Throwable throwable)`

```
...
catch (e: Exception) {
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
}
...
```

Here is [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android#crashlyticslogexceptionthrowable_is_replaced_by_firebasecrashlyticsrecordexceptionthrowable) stating that

Comment: I could not find this `recordException(e)` i think it has removed

Comment: Thank you for the link, a lot of the Firebase "getting started" docs omit the Crashlytics dependencies for some reason, but the "upgrade" guide that you posted is complete and accurate.

Comment: @miladsalimi maybe you were using `FirebaseAnalytics` instead of `FirebaseCrashlytics`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use

`FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)`

to log non fatal issues on crashlytics

Comment: not working for me
same code i put in my app. i have daily 3K user but firebase did not show me one crash.

Comment: Kindly check if it is properly initialized in Application class. Share your code, so that we can help you

Comment: there is no method named 'logException' in Crashlytics

Comment: how to see non fatal logs in firebase crashlytics console?

Comment: See [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#log_non-fatal_exceptions). You can also attach additional information to the crash report with `Crashlytics.log`. More [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#add_custom_log_messages).

Comment: @Nainal in Firebase, go to Crashlytics, then change the filter event type to non-fatals.

Comment: @David I have done this but nothing appears in the console.

Comment: Doublecheck if you have selected the correct app. I was looking at the release version while there was also a logging for the debug version

Comment: Nov 2019
Try: `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(Throwable(message))`

Comment: Hi with this line can we see the none fatal exception in firebase???

Comment: yes. Firebase used Crashlytics now. So it'll be visible in firebase

Comment: There is no class called "Crashlytics".

Comment: @AndrewKoster use ```FirebaseCrashlytics``` instead. ```Crashlytics``` is the old's Fabric version.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you add the following codes in you `Application` class which you attached in your `AndroidManifest.xml` -

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        .
        .
        .
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Then call the method where expected -

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(myException)
```

Comment: `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` is not required, It is handled internally by the Firebase libraries when initialised by the `ContentProvider`s. Also `setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled` is enabled by default, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Module build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  android {...

 dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:17.2.1'
```

Project build.gradle

```
   dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
         lateinit var mCrash: FirebaseCrashlytics           
         lateinit var instance: MainActivity
         private set
     }
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         instance = this
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(instance)
         mCrash = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
           val exception = Exception("test Exception")
           mCrash.recordException(exception)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, take care that `recordException(e)` method doesn't send exceptions in time to crashlytics as it's mentioned in their [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#java)

> Crashlytics batches logged exceptions together and sends them the next time the app launches.